# Error in single php line : Parse error: /wp-includes/option.php wp_cache_add

Tags: php, wordpress

The website randomly went down and I can't figure out how to correct the following error. I have tried toggling all plugins, the server was recently updated to `PHP 7.4` from `PHP 7.3` but no other website has had this issue.

My Setup:

```
PHP - PHP 7.4.11 (cli) (built: Oct  8 2020 17:32:43)

uname - Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux

MySQL - mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Error from the website:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_add()
> in /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/option.php:258 Stack trace: #0
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/functions.php(1717): wp_load_alloptions() #1
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/load.php(664): is_blog_installed() #2
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed() #3
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-config.php(99): require_once('/home/swcsoldie...') #4
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/swcsoldie...') #5
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once('/home/swcsoldie...') #6 /WEBSITE_PATH/index.php(22):
> require('/home/swcsoldie...') #7 {main} thrown in
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/option.php on line 258
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_add()
> in /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/option.php:258 Stack trace: #0
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/option.php(116): wp_load_alloptions() #1
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/l10n.php(69): get_option() #2
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/l10n.php(137): get_locale() #3
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/l10n.php(828): determine_locale() #4
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(46):
> load_default_textdomain() #5 [internal function]:
> WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #6 {main} thrown in
> /WEBSITE_PATH/wp-includes/option.php on line 258

Code from Line 258:

```
wp_cache_add( 'alloptions', $alloptions, 'options' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `undefined function` error in PHP is fatal error, and means you're calling a function that doesn't exist (at least, at the point and scope it's being called at). Most often, I'd wager 9/10 times, this happens while you're developing and you mistype a function name, `str_repace` instead of `str_replace`, for instance.

With all of that being said, [`wp_cache_add()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_add/) is a WordPress Core function defined in `/wp-includes/cache.php`, and is being called by a core file: `/wp-includes/option.php` on line 258.

Since these *core files, and core functions* are triggering a fatal "undefined function" error, it means your WordPress installation is failing somewhere. It possibly got corrupted during an update of some kind - it's infrequent, but it *does* happen for any number of reasons.

To fix this: try reinstalling WordPress, as it is [*absolutely* compatible with PHP 7.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/11/wordpress-and-php-7-4/).

Comment: No matter how much, you don't hear it enough. I LOVE YOU! I've banged my head on a wall for a while. Thank you soo soo much